# Find all ERDs containing table with specified name

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, erd

Is it possible that I can query for names of all ERDs (Entity Relationship Diagram) which contain table with name

```
Like '%mytable%'
```

Something like this:

```
select * 
from <ERD objects> 
where tableName like '%%'
```

Actually, I have a large `Database` with lots of `ERDs`. So, to understand the scope of a table I want to browse `ERDs` of that specific table.

Comment: use information_schema.tables view

Comment: Can't find ERD name where a table is used.

Comment: what is erd ?please look here on how to improve question.Your question is confusing .https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: erd means entity relationship diagram.

Comment: You need to search in ALL databases or only one specific?

Comment: I want to search in only one specific database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand you need a  list of tables contained in a database diagrams. There you can help this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15080/Script-SQL-Server-diagrams-to-a-file?msg=4914888#xx4914888xx). I will add part of it here:

The diagram itself is stored in a binary field. And you can not convert it into *readable* form without difficulties. For deserializing this field (called `definition`) we need 2 functions:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Tool_VarbinaryToVarchar_Text]
(
    @VarbinaryValue VARBINARY(max),
    @bitASCIIOnly   BIT = 0
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(max) AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @NumberOfBytes  INT

SET @NumberOfBytes = DATALENGTH(@VarbinaryValue)
-- PART ONE --
IF (@NumberOfBytes > 4)
BEGIN
    DECLARE @FirstHalfNumberOfBytes INT
    DECLARE @SecondHalfNumberOfBytes INT
    SET @FirstHalfNumberOfBytes  = @NumberOfBytes/2
    SET @SecondHalfNumberOfBytes = @NumberOfBytes - @FirstHalfNumberOfBytes
    -- Call this function recursively with the two parts of the input split in half
    RETURN dbo.Tool_VarbinaryToVarchar_Text(CAST(SUBSTRING(@VarbinaryValue, 1                           , @FirstHalfNumberOfBytes)  AS VARBINARY(max)),@bitASCIIOnly)
         + dbo.Tool_VarbinaryToVarchar_Text(CAST(SUBSTRING(@VarbinaryValue, @FirstHalfNumberOfBytes+1 , @SecondHalfNumberOfBytes) AS VARBINARY(max)),@bitASCIIOnly)
END

IF (@NumberOfBytes = 0)
BEGIN
    RETURN ''   -- No bytes found, therefore no 'hex string' is returned
END

-- PART TWO --
DECLARE @HighByte       INT
-- @NumberOfBytes <= 4 (four or less characters/8 hex digits were input)
--                       eg. 88887777 66665555 44443333 22221111
-- We'll process ONLY the right-most (least-significant) Byte, which consists
-- of eight bits

-- 2. Carve off the rightmost eight bits/single hex digit (ie 22221111)
--    Divide by 16 does a shift-left (now processing 2222)
SET @HighByte = CAST(@VarbinaryValue AS INT) & 255
IF @bitASCIIOnly = 1 AND (@HighByte < 32 OR @HighByte > 126) SET @HighByte=13;

-- 3. Trim the byte (two hex values) from the right (least significant) input Binary
--    in preparation for further parsing
SET @VarbinaryValue = SUBSTRING(@VarbinaryValue, 1, (@NumberOfBytes-1))

-- 4. Recursively call this method on the remaining Binary data, concatenating the text 
--    'value' we just decoded as their ASCII character representation
--    ie. we pass 88887777 66665555 44443333 back to this function, adding X to the result string
RETURN dbo.Tool_VarbinaryToVarchar_Text(@VarbinaryValue,@bitASCIIOnly) + 

CHAR(@HighByte)
END
```

And:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnTool_ScriptDiagram2005_Text]()
RETURNS 
@tblOut TABLE 
(
    -- Add the column definitions for the TABLE variable here
    diagramname     NVARCHAR(128), 
    diagram_id      INT PRIMARY KEY,
    diagram_text    VARCHAR(MAX),
    diagram_ASCII   VARCHAR(MAX)
)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @name           NVARCHAR(128);
    DECLARE @diagram_id     INT;
    DECLARE @index          INT;
    DECLARE @size           INT;
    DECLARE @chunk          INT;
    DECLARE @line           VARCHAR(MAX);
    DECLARE @lineASC        VARCHAR(MAX);
    DECLARE @CurrentPos     INT;
    SELECT @CurrentPos = MIN(diagram_id) FROM dbo.sysdiagrams;

    WHILE (@CurrentPos IS NOT NULL)
    BEGIN
        -- Set start index, and chunk 'constant' value
        SET @index = 1;     -- 
        SET @chunk = 32;    -- values that work: 2, 6
                            -- values that fail: 15,16, 64

        SELECT  @diagram_id = diagram_id,
                @size = DATALENGTH(definition),
                @name = name
          FROM dbo.sysdiagrams 
         WHERE diagram_id = @CurrentPos;

        -- Now with the diagram_id, do all the work

        SET @line = '';
        SET @lineASC = '';
        WHILE @index < @size
        BEGIN
            -- Output as many UPDATE statements as required to append all the diagram binary
            -- data, represented as hexadecimal strings
            SELECT  @line = @line + dbo.Tool_VarbinaryToVarchar_Text(SUBSTRING (definition, @index, @chunk),0),
                    @lineASC = @lineASC + dbo.Tool_VarbinaryToVarchar_Text(SUBSTRING (definition, @index, @chunk),1)
              FROM  dbo.sysdiagrams 
             WHERE  diagram_id = @CurrentPos;

            SET @index = @index + @chunk;
        END
        INSERT INTO @tblOut (diagramname, diagram_id, diagram_text, diagram_ASCII)
             VALUES         (@name,      @diagram_id, @line,        REPLACE(@lineASC,CHAR(13),''));
        SELECT @CurrentPos = MIN(diagram_id)
          FROM dbo.sysdiagrams
         WHERE diagram_id > @CurrentPos;
    END
    RETURN;
END
```

After that you can run:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [dbo].[fnTool_ScriptDiagram2005_Text] ()
WHERE diagram_ASCII LIKE '%TableToFind%'
```

For example I have created diagram `TestDiagram` with 2 tables named `whatever` and `IE_Stat`. In return query:

> Root EntrypfoBCompObj_ !"#$%&'()*+,-.123456789:(}5n]4o[\0V?[?i???V?[?i??T,,,4") -bH''Uu94941#xV4XdboIE_StatMicrosoft DDS Form 2.0Embedded Object9q&sch_labels_visibled(ActiveTableViewMode1 TableViewMode:0:4,0,28DdsStreamSchema UDV Default&/DSREF-SCHEMA-CONTENTS,0Schema UDV Default Post V66;4,0,2310,1,1890,5,1260 TableViewMode:12,0,284,0,2805 TableViewMode:22,0,284,0,2310 TableViewMode:32,0,284,0,2310 TableViewMode:4>4,0,284,0,2310,12,2730,11,1680(ActiveTableViewMode1 TableViewMode:0:4,0,284,0,2310,1,1890,5,1260 TableViewMode:12,0,284,0,2805 TableViewMode:22,0,284,0,2310 TableViewMode:32,0,284,0,2310 TableViewMode:4>4,0,284,0,2310,12,2730,11,1680NaQW9 LHEData Source=********;Initial Catalog=test;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;Packet Size=4096;Application Name="Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio"TestDiagram&whateverdbo$IE_StatdbokE7d2pN{1634CDD7-0888-42E3-9FA2-B6D32563B91D}bR

you can see both table names.

Comment: Thanks for your response but I am unable to find name of ERD where a table is used. A table can be used more than one ERDs.

Comment: I misunderstood you at first. Now I changed my answer. Please, have a look.

Comment: Thanks that great. It really helped me.